# gap borders' right and left

Tags: css, html

When I applied padding to 'a' elements, there will be gaps top-borders' left and right.I want the top border covers entire line until navbar's right border. How can I solve this problem.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 6fr;
}

.navbar {
  border-right: gray 3px solid;
  padding: 5%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 300px;
}

#navbar-header {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#navbar-content a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#navbar-content a li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5%;
  padding-left: 10%;
  border-top: gray 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="navbar">
    <h2 id="navbar-header">JS Documentation</h2>
    <ul id="navbar-content">
      <a href="#intro">
        <li>Introduction</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#know">
        <li>What you should already know</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#js-java">
        <li>JavaScript and Java</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#hello">
        <li>Hello World</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#var">
        <li>Variables</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#dec-var">
        <li>Declaring Variables</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#var-sco">
        <li>Variable Scope</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#glo-var">
        <li>Global Variables</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#cons">
        <li>Constants</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#data">
        <li>Data Types</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#if-else">
        <li>if...else statement</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#while">
        <li>while statement</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#func">
        <li>Function declarations</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#ref">
        <li>Reference</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="contents">

  </div>
</div>
```

When I applied padding to 'a' elements, there will be gaps top-borders' left and right.I want the top border covers entire line until navbar's right border. How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the padding-left/right from the navbar and increase the one of the `li`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 6fr;
}

.navbar {
  border-right: gray 3px solid;
  padding: 5% 0; /*updated*/
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 300px;
}

#navbar-header {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#navbar-content a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#navbar-content a li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5% 10%; /*updated*/
  border-top: gray 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="navbar">
    <h2 id="navbar-header">JS Documentation</h2>
    <ul id="navbar-content">
      <a href="#intro">
        <li>Introduction</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#know">
        <li>What you should already know</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#js-java">
        <li>JavaScript and Java</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#hello">
        <li>Hello World</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#var">
        <li>Variables</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#dec-var">
        <li>Declaring Variables</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#var-sco">
        <li>Variable Scope</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#glo-var">
        <li>Global Variables</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#cons">
        <li>Constants</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#data">
        <li>Data Types</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#if-else">
        <li>if...else statement</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#while">
        <li>while statement</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#func">
        <li>Function declarations</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#ref">
        <li>Reference</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="contents">

  </div>
</div>
```